# Manage menu button of device

Tags: android, menu

In some of devices,the device hase menu button. I want, when i am in my app and click on the menu button of device, i see a spectial form like settings menu of many apps but this show in bottom . How can i write this? Please give me idea or link for reading. I searched but i can't find solution. Thanks for advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

   // call your menu button method
   return true;
}

// let the system handle all other key events
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And keep your own `menu button`

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_bytton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
});
```

Comment: i want manage special hardwar key in my app, this key like home button. I think this is false. Do i use onOptionsMenuSelected for this??

Comment: onOptionsMenus()? Do we use this for manage hardware key of device? or home button of device? Sure?

Comment: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU handles menu not home button.

Comment: for sense menu button, i use KEYCODE_MENU and then i show popupmenu this is true? but another question why you use onKeyDown() and not use onKeyUp()? and why you use Button and implement onClick()method? Thanks

Comment: Actually what you are talking is not clear. Can you make it clear

Comment: I say, you write a snippet code for me, and in this, you use KEYCODE_MENU, i say, KEYCODE_MENU is for sense, click on menu key of device? Why you use onKeyDown()method? why dont use onKeyUp() method? Do you understand what i say?

Comment: OnKeyUp will trigger the key event handled by the system, So you cant handle that, Using OnkeyDown you can consume that event and do your own work

Comment: but i see in some of liks, writes OnKeyUp for manage hardware menu key.. How can they use this if this use for system?? and another thing, when in this method i want call popupMenu(context,view), what send instead of view ? Thanks :)